# How to update locally created R package without reinstalling

Tags: r, devtools

I created an R package using this [tutorial](http://tinyheero.github.io/jekyll/update/2015/07/26/making-your-first-R-package.html). The package loads just fine when called but requires a bit debugging. After debugging my script, I used  `devtools::update_packages("new_package")` to fix the changes, but I receive the following error: `Skipping 1 packages not available: new_package` (interestingly, `new_package` shows up when I call `installed.packages()`).

I'm able to update my package by reinstalling with `devtools::install("new_package")`, but for simple fixes this doesn't seem very efficient. Perhaps there is another way? I appreciate any help or insight.

EDIT for clarification:
I understand the package needs to be reloaded to update changes, but reloading the package using `library(mypackage)` (after detaching the package or starting a new session) **does not** accomplish this while `devtools::update_packages("path/to/mypackage")` does. Per the tutorial, I decided to install my package using `devtools::install()`. Is this because the process of installing my homebrew package requires setting up repository for updates?

Comment: Have you tried just `devtools::load_all("path/to/mypackage")`? There is no other way to fix any changes in the function; either reload the whole package or don't.

Comment: Note that you can also use RStudio shortcuts to load the package, e.g. (I think) Ctrl+Shift+L by default. This is much faster than installing and simulates installing fairly closely

Comment: r2evans, please see my updated question.